# ggplot2, why so blue? How to set a different color palette in gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient

Why doesn't this pick up the green colors?  It stays blue...

```
require(ggplot2)
data(iris)
ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,col=Petal.Length,pch=Species,size=Petal.Width))+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="green",high="darkgreen")+
  ggtitle('Why so blue?')+geom_point()
```

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Nice title. Good pun, *and* I correctly anticipated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've used `scale_fill_gradient()`, yet your `aes()` contains a color argument. Try `scale_color_gradient()` instead.

```
data(iris)
ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,
                col=Petal.Length,pch=Species,size=Petal.Width))+
scale_color_gradient(low="green",high="darkgreen")+
ggtitle('Now so green')+geom_point()
```

Output:

[image]

**Explanation:**

Whether to use scale_fill or scale_color is determined by the arguments supplied to the aes() portion of ggplot code. Color arguments are typically used for things like geom_point() and geom_line(); fill arguments are typically used for the color of bars in a bar graph for example.

Comment: When do I use scale_fill_gradient?

Comment: When you use a `fill` aesthetic. Here you're using a `colour` aesthetic (`col=Petal.Length`). You could use a `fill` aesthetic with `geom_point`, but that would affect the plot colors only if you use a filled point marker (pch 21-25 are filled point markers). A fill aesthetic might also be used for a bar plot or a ribbon plot (for example, for the fill color of a confidence interval when plotting regression lines.

Comment: @Chris - Good question. Just edited an explanation into my answer.